# Is there a way to scrape a website using just HTML and CSS (no JavaScript)?

Tags: html, css, web-scraping

I would like to scrape a website to copy text and display it on my web page. I know there are plenty of ways to do this with Python, JavaScript...etc, but I would like to keep this project contained in that one HTML file. Any help appreciated!

Comment: No, you cannot do such things with HTML (I'm not the one who downvoted). If you want to keep it contained in one HTML file, you can probably try to use `<script>` tags and put JS code in them, something like: `<script>//your web-scraping code</script>`.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder — No. The same origin policy prevents that.

Answer (score 3):

HTML and CSS do not have that capability.

You need a programming language to do programming.

(Even JS embedded in an HTML document can't do that due to the Same Origin Policy).

Answer (score 1):

No.
HTML is a markup language.  It defines structures and things, it doesn't traverse or negotiate or conditionally do anything.

CSS is a language for defining styles for markup.  It's not capable of scraping anything.

You need a programming language in order to scrape a site's code.